# Convert an Int to a WinTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, int

I want to put the result of an operation (Integer) inside a TextBox (`System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`)

I tried using the `Convert.ToString()` function, but it's not working.

How can i do this?

Comment: So like, myTextbox.Text = Convert.ToString(1+1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
Textbox1.Text=integervariable.Tostring();
```

Comment: Please feel free to mark as answer by clicking on the TICK mark to the left of the answer if it clears your doubt,Regards..